# iOs Swift: How to pass a task to the background thread?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

In my iOS app I have a task that is executed perodically with a timer (the task is checking my database every 10 seconds):

```
var timer: dispatch_source_t!; 
timer = Dispatch.timerAsync(interval: intervalTime){
    //my task here
}
```

if a speciifc parameter in my database is set then I stop the timer and process the results (including updating the UI) in the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {            
    self.processResults();          
}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to make this work when the user switches to another app. When my app goes to the background the timer stops working and when I go back to my app it starts working again. I wanted to know if it is possible to pass this task with the timer to the background thread when the user switches to another app so that my app still checks the database every 10 seconds and if the parameter in the database is set the user gets a notification (local notification). I would like to avoid using Apple's remote notification if possible... Is this possible?

I don't have enough experience with app programming so I wanted to get some idea to see if I'm approaching this problem the right away. Any input, suggestion or sample code is very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can, theoretically, keep it going for a few minutes after the app is suspended with [`beginBackgroundTaskWithidentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623051-beginbackgroundtaskwithname?language=objc). But that doesn't work beyond a few minutes. For the sake of our batteries and device performance, Apple doesn't let apps run perpetually in the background (with narrow exceptions). Besides, this whole idea of polling the database every 10 seconds is pretty darn inefficient. If the database is on a remote server, the right solution really is a push notification.

Comment: Or if you want your app to periodically check for new data, you can use background fetch (see [Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56)). But that runs at the discretion of the OS and nowhere close to every few seconds (more like every few hours/days, depending upon how often user runs your app, how often there is new data, whether its on wifi and charging, etc.).

Comment: See the [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) chapter of the _App Programming Guide for iOS_ for full discussion of the background execution options.